# How do you create a folder on a home screen in Honeycomb 3.0.1 (Xoom)?

Tags: 3.0-honeycomb, motorola-xoom, home-screen-folders

I was rather shocked to learn that my Xoom tablet, running Honeycomb (3.0.1) does not support the ability to group home screen shortcuts into folders.  Nor does it seem to provide a stock widget that could be used for organizing shortcuts.

Coming from a Froyo (DroidX) phone and iPad, both of which have long supported folder functionality, this is a huge surprise and my only big disappointment with Honeycomb.

I have found 3rd party apps that can help this ([Folder Organizer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.abcOrganizer&feature=search_result)), but this App is overly complex for the given task.  If anyone can recommend an app that does nothing but simple iOS-like folder organization, that would be great. (I realize there are many alternative launcher/homescreen repplacements that support folders, but would rather not broaden the discussion that far for now).

I find it embarrassing to have to explain to iPad users that Honeycomb does not have anything like folder organization for apps built-in to the OS.  Is this a design "feature" of Android?   Does Google prefer another method for organizing home screen icons?  Is it coming in a future release?

Comment: I didn't even realize this was missing (but then again, I didn't use folders on my phone either). The only other folder app I've used before is App Oragnizer https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.code.appsorganizer

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Smart Shortcuts](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.rhmsoft.shortcuts&feature=search_result) (lets you organize applications and bookmarks in folders using tags), of the Astro file manager, which let you add shortcuts to folders of the filesystem.

Comment: Smart Shortcuts won't let you put a folder on the desktop. It does the same thing all of these shortcut programs do - it puts links to your apps in a window on the desktop that pops open from an icon. It's not really a folder. I need an actual folder that will support drag and drop of shortcuts on the desktop to specific files, not applications. For example I need to be able to put the shortcuts to dozens of pdf's in a folder on the desktop. Please don't answer with Astro will let you put a link to the folder containing them. The links put there by Astro will not stay to the same folder. The a