# How to rate an app in Android Market on a tablet?

Tags: google-play-store, tablet

I know this question sounds dead stupid but I can't figure out how to rate an app in Android Market on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1. Honestly I've looked everywhere. Am I blind or what?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Related: [How can I rate an app in Honeycomb?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9497/how-can-i-rate-an-app-in-honeycomb)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first versions of the Android Market on Tablets didn't have an option to rate an App. Rumors are that Google wanted to prevent bad ratings on Apps, because they weren't optimized for tables (yet).

Some say that they received an Market Update that enabled the rate function. My Lenovo Thinkpad Market hasn't got it yet. But it seems just a matter of time.

Until then, you can rate Apps on the [web version of the Market.](https://market.android.com/)

Comment: PS: So, good news: You are not blind. :)

Comment: In Samsung's case it seems to be that they use a non-standard version of the Market for some reason. It reports itself on my Tab 10.1 as version 1.0.28. On a typical Honeycomb device you simply need to have the 3.1.6 update to be able to rate apps.

Comment: I have v1.1.0 on my tablet. The publisher is Google Inc. but I suppose it could be a custom version for Samsung. I'll just keep using my Galaxy Tab (phone) to rate apps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are an update on the way from google which gives you the option, many have received it already, so just be use the web version of android market until then :)